# (Java) Printing text letter by letter in console- ft. Lag

Tags: java, text, console, lag

so I'm making a game that uses nothing but the console in my java IDE, but I have a problem using delays. My goal is to create a method that when taken a text passed though the parameters, it prints it letter by letter with a delay of 50. (Kind of like the text in the Pokemon series, how it scrolls though each letter).

The problem I have is lag. I'm running an amd fx-8350 cpu (4GHz, 4 cores+4 virtual cores). Whenever I change the delay amount to anything around and under 100 milliseconds, the console prints half a word, then a little bit of the other half, then half the sentence, then maybe a character, etc.

I've tried this code here (it works, but with lag):

```
public void scroll(String text){
    int delay = 50;
    ActionListener action = new ActionListener()
    {
        int counter = text.length();
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            if(counter == 0)
            {
                timer.stop();
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print(text.substring(text.length() - counter, ((text.length() - counter) + 1)));
                counter--;
            }
        }
    };
    timer = new Timer(delay, action);
    timer.start();

}//end scroll
```

And this code as well (also works, with same amount of lag):

```
public void scroll(String text){
    for(int i = 0; i <= text.length(); i++){
       try {
               Thread.sleep(1000);
            }catch(InterruptedException ex){
               Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
       System.out.print(text.substring(i, i + 1));
    }
}//end scroll
```

In conclusion, I'm guessing that the computer is doing more than "delaying" when I try to delay the thread. Any idea's?

-Thanks, Eric

Comment: Try adding `System.out.flush` after each print.

Comment: No difference in both examples :(  By the way I'm using intelliJ (if that makes a difference, doubt it will)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, some random notes about your code. This is wrong:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= text.length(); i++){
```

Whether you are iterating through a string, array, list, or whatever, the usual pattern is always

```
i = 0; i < length; i++
```

i.e. by using `<=` you are getting an exception. This is unneeded:

```
text.substring(i, i + 1)
```

and it looks even worse in the first example. You can use `text.charAr(i)`.

---

I tried this code as an alternative:

```
for(int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while (System.currentTimeMillis() - start < 50) {

    }
    System.out.print(text.charAt(i));
}
```

It still didn't work in IntelliJ. However it and your code work fine in the terminal, so I think IntelliJ just doesn't like printing immediately. `flush` makes no difference but its documentation in `OutputStream` hints at what might be happening:

> If the intended destination of this stream is an abstraction provided by the underlying operating system, for example a file, then flushing the stream guarantees only that bytes previously written to the stream are passed to the operating system for writing; it does not guarantee that they are actually written to a physical device such as a disk drive.

So again, I think the IDE is the problem and it's out of the control of your code.